# Petrol stations with free wifi in Iceland

Tags: iceland, wifi

I've read [here](http://www.myguiadeviajes.com/2013/04/islandia-low-cost-10-ideas-para-ahorrar-viajando/) (Spanish) that "most petrol stations and visitor centers have free wifi". Is true? Is there any list of petrol stations with wifi?

Comment: You may want to clarify why this may be of any interest for travellers. This is not factoids-about-every-countries-I-wasnt-born-in

Comment: I think that is obvious: when you travel by car in Iceland you need to check the weather and road conditions every day.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't know that petrol station was the word for gas station in Australia, I thought you were referring to a oil/petrol platform.

Comment: I've read the same thing on the lonely planet guide I just bought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, major petrol stations do have wifi, such as [all the N1 stations](http://iceland.nordicvisitor.com/travel-guide/information/) (company name).  However it's only *usually* free.

- a list of all the [N1 service stations](http://www.n1.is/n1/en/service/service/service_stations/)
- [all the OLIS stations](http://www.olis.is/english/stations/), with the option to filter all the ones with free wifi
- [all the Skeljunger stations](http://skeljungur.is/pages/453)

It's also available at [tourist information centres](http://www.extremeiceland.is/en/information/about-iceland/useful-information) and at all branches of the city library.

Vodafone also has a wide net of internet hotspots, with a [listing of all their locations online](http://www.vodafone.is/internet/heitirreitir/).